# Rspec controller tests with chaining method calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

My controller looks like this:

```rb
def index
  params[:page]||1
  @stories = Story.all.page(params[:page]).per(5)
end
```

When I try to write controller tests for the chaining line through using RSpec, I can't seem to get the tests to pass.

My controller_spec looks something like:

```rb
describe '#index' do
  let(:story) {double(Story)}
  before do
    allow(Story).to receive(:all).and_return(story)
    allow(story).to receive(:page).and_return(story)
    allow(story).to receive(:per).and_return(story)                                                                                                         
    get :index
  end
  context 'when user is not logged in' do
    it 'should get page 1' do                                                                                                
      expect(story).to receive(:page).with(1)                                                                                                               
    end
    it 'should get 5 stories' do
      expect(story).to receive(:per).with(5)                                                                                                                
    end
  end
end
```

What would be good example test to write for such a controller?

Comment: At least in first allow you should use `allow_any_instance_of(Story)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `expect(story).to receive(:page).with(1)` before calling `get :index`

move `get :index` from `before` block to `it` block:

```
it 'should get page 1' do                                                                                                
  expect(story).to receive(:page).with(1)
  get :index
end
```

PS and it looks like you missed `=` in controller action

```
params[:page] ||= 1
```

Comment: Thanks! You caught my mistake with the `get :index`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use something like this:

```
def index
  params[:page] ||= 1
  @stories = Story.all.page(params[:page]).per(5)
end

describe '#index' do
  let(:stories) { [double(Story)] }
  let(:index) { -> { get :index, page: 1, pre: 5 } }

  context 'when user is not logged in' do
    it 'should get 5 last stories and assign to @stories' do
      expect_any_instance_of(Story).to receive(:all).and_return(stories)
      expect_any_instance_of(Story).to receive(:page).with(1).and_return(stories)
      expect_any_instance_of(Story).to receive(:per).with(5).and_return(stories)

      index.()
    end
  end
end
```

Your methods returns Enum of stories, not some story. When you make it return one story it's wrong. You probably want to check the order of this methods, and you can do it [with this](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains) but they don't check receiving parameters.

If you don't care about params or you should add extra check you can do it with this:

```
describe '#index' do
  let(:stories) { [double(Story)] }

  context 'when user is not logged in' do
    it 'should get 5 last stories and assign to @stories' do
      expect_any_instance_of(Story).to receive(:all).and_return(stories)
      expect(stories).to receive(:page).and_return(stories)
      expect(stories).to receive(:per).and_return(stories)

      # or probably just this
      expect_any_instance_of(Story).to receive_message_chain(:all, :page, :per) { stories }

      get :index
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just learnt that a double is actually an instance of Story instead of being a double of the class itself. My mistake was actually with the placement of get `:index` as mentioned by @gotva.

Comment: I like your second solution. Seems a lot cleaner. I tried message chain but I couldn't specify the arguments in each chain so I decided to find another way.